# display json array values into a list using its id in a html page

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, phonegap-build

iam working on mobile app. in my controller i created a json array and iam trying to display the array values into a list in my html page. i want show the list when html page is automatically loaded.

actually my json array contains **'category_id'**  $  **'category_name'** and iam looking  forward to next page when click on the **'category_name'**

**nextPage.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>     
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/nextPage.js"></script>    
   <title>Edfutura1</title>
  </head>
  <center>
 <body id="category_id">
 <div data-role="page" id="catlist"> 
 <div  id="loading" > </div>  
 <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
 <h1>category</h1>
 </div> 
 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">


            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="category">
              <li></li>        
            </ul> 

        </div>

 </div>                 
 </body>
</center>
 </html>
```

**nextPage.js**

```
 var base_url="http://dev.edfutura.com/nithin/jps/edfuturaMob/";  
 $(document).on("pageinit","#catlist", function() {
 var submitUrl = base_url+"categorylist/get_categorylist"; 
 $("#loading").css("display", "block");
 $.ajax({
        url: submitUrl,

        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response)
        {
         //do something pls  
         },
         error: function() 
        {
            alert("error");

        }

    });





     });
```

**categorylist.php**

```
 function get_categorylist() 
 {
   $cat=$this->categorylist_model->get_cat(); 


   echo json_encode($cat);  

  }
```

**my json array**

```
 [{"category_id":"1","category_name":"Academic Analysis"},         {"category_id":"2","category_name":"Teaching Analysis"},{"category_id":"3","category_name":"Skill Analysis"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `response` in the `$.ajax` success function. This `response` object should be your json object and can therefore easily be accessed via the specified properties `category_name` and `category_id`.

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(response){
        // do something with the json response! E.g. generate a new list item and append it to the list.
        var categoryList = $('#category');
        var category;
        for(var i = 0, len = response.length; i < len; i++){
            category = response[i];
            categoryList.append($('<li>').attr('id', category.category_id).html(category.category_name));
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: i got one error like this                                                                                                           **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dev.edfutura.com/nithin/jps/edfuturaMob/categorylist/get_categorylist. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

Comment: That's because you cannot easily query other sites/domains from the client. Keywords: Cross-Domain-Requests and Same-Origin-Policy. You can avoid this e.g. by querying on the server side using cURL.